# Are movies made for Netflix eligible for Academy Awards?

Tags: academy-awards, netflix

These days Netflix is making movies for itself, such as *Bright* starring Will Smith. There are many more movies made for Netflix.

Are these movies eligible for Academy Awards, as they are made for a web based platform?

Comment: Probably not unless they comply with the rules - http://www.oscars.org/sites/oscars/files/89aa_rules.pdf I believe it has to run  in **theatres** first too qualify.

Comment: Not that any of the Netflix movies has come any closer to AA quality...

Comment: Even if they were, the academy awards are notoriously a collection of back scratching money men that would reduce the chances of a legitimate win according to the viewers as close to none as possible unless someone at the awards felt it was an opportune move for the future of the awards and the guild they serve. If they wanted Netflix drowned in the technicalities, they would institute a collection of rules that would be too hard to meet, or would be easily refuted by any other mainstream title... oh wait, they did.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Movies made for anyone, including Netflix, are eligible for Academy Awards, but only if they complete a 7-day release in Los Angeles County.

> - **for paid admission in a commercial motion picture theater in Los Angeles County**,
> - **for a qualifying run of at least seven consecutive days, during which period screenings must occur at least three times daily, with at least one screening beginning between 6 p.m. and 10 p.m. daily**,
> - advertised and exploited during their Los Angeles County qualifying run in a manner normal and customary to theatrical feature distribution practices, and
> - released within the Awards year deadlines specified in Rule Three.

Also

> 3. Films that, in any version, receive their first public exhibition or distribution in any manner other than as a theatrical motion picture release will not be eligible for Academy Awards in any category.  Nontheatrical public exhibition or distribution includes but is not limited to:
>
>    - Broadcast and cable television
>    - PPV/VOD
>    - DVD distribution
>    - Internet transmission
>
>    Motion pictures released in such nontheatrical media on or after the first day of their Los Angeles County qualifying run remain eligible. Also, ten minutes or ten percent of the running time of a film, whichever is shorter, may be shown in a nontheatrical medium prior to the film’s qualifying run.

<sub>[Source](http://www.oscars.org/sites/oscars/files/90aa_rules.pdf)</sub>

Comment: Maybe (documentary) shorts can be made for Netflix and then take another route to eligibility?  Those don't need to have been commercially released if they have won awards at a set festivals.

Comment: @gerrit Those short films should run in theater first before getting released on Netflix in order to become eligible. But the Netflix wants to release them on both platforms on the same day. This is something the members of Academy aren't agreeing to. See the linked article.

Comment: The way I read the "ACADEMY AWARDS OF MERIT" in the PDF you linked, the commercial theatre release is not the only route to eligibility for shorts:  "(...) must have been publicly exhibited (...) OR must have won a qualifying award at a 
competitive film festival (...) OR must have won a (...) Medal award in the Academy’s 2017 Student Academy Awards competition (...)" (page 27).  I interpret that as shorts being potentially eligible without any commercial theatre release, if they have won awards elsewhere.  Am I misreading this?

Comment: @gerrit No, you're not. It's correct. If they have won a qualifying award at a competitive
film festival, they can be eligible without having any theatrical run.

Comment: @AJ Are you forgetting about Mudbound? That's a Netflix-distributed movie that's up for an Oscar this year. It had a one week run in LA and NY. So... the answer is yes, for movies that fulfill the requirements. And that's already happened once.

Comment: @sgroves The rule I mentioned in my previous comment applies for documentary short, featured animated movie etc.

Comment: @AJ I'm referring to your answer. `Till date, they're not.` is not true because of Mudbound... maybe I'm missing something, though.

Comment: @AJ What? You don't mention Mudbound anywhere. My point is that Netflix could easily put all of its movies into one theater for a week in order to make them eligible for the Oscars. *And they've already done that once.* Really, the answer to OP's question is categorically *YES*, if Netflix wants to. It's entirely up to Netflix.

Comment: @AJ Now that you've removed the first sentence, it makes sense. Thanks. No reason to act like it wasn't wrong in the first place, though. >_>

Comment: @sgroves I didn't know what was the confusion here. I realized that the first sentence is confusing, so I removed it.

Comment: @AJ Honestly I'm also confused by the latter half of your answer. We know the Academy allows Netflix movies, because Mudbound received nominations. Maybe that is simply outdated information?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73216/discussion-between-a-j-and-sgroves).

Comment: @sgroves I used the information from the rules of 90th academy awards provided on the site of Academy Awards. I have already linked it.

Comment: I'm very curious to see how Scorsese's The Irishman does considering it will drop on Netflix and be in theaters, but I hear they haven't fully settled on how this will work. It may be that it will be released theatrically first and then on Netflix 2-3 months later, because Scorsese may not want to fully experiment. But Roma should be a good example to us all!

Answer (score 2):

*Roma* (2018) has won three Academy Awards including Best Director, Best Cinematography and Best Foreign language film. It was nominated for 10 categories in the 91st Academy Awards. It had a short theatrical release to satisfy it with the rules of Academy.[image]

Comment: If you could add a source just to better establish this, it might improve the answer, but 1+ for great example! :)

Comment: Problem is, we're not really looking for examples of cool Netflix films here, rather than *if* those films are even eligible for Oscars or not. The only part of your answer that adresses this is the last sentence. But this is really only a shorter and an unsourced variation of the already accepted answer.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson what do you mean by unsourced Roma has won the Academy Awards this year. This [link](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6155172/) of its IMDb page shows that it has won 3 Oscars. Also, Netflix is one of its producers.

Comment: this [link]  
 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_original_films_distributed_by_Netflix#Original_films) shows that Roma is a Netflix original film. Also, you can visit its official Wikipedia [page] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roma_(2018_film) which states that it was released on 21st November 2018 in selected theatres and released on Netflix on 14th December 2018.As per US norms, a film must release for digital platforms only after 90 days of its theatrical release but this was not the case for this movie.It released on Netflix just after 3 weeks.

Comment: No, the statement that it *"had a short theatrical release to satisfy it with the rules of Academy"* is the *unsourced* part, as that is also the only part relevant for the question. As said, we're not looking for *examples* of Netflix films that won Oscars, there's no doubt this film won Oscars, but for explanations *if* they can and *how* they can so, in which regard this answer is really only a less explanative version of the accepted answer of.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only in 2020 for the 93rd Oscars, according to the [Academy](https://www.oscars.org/news/awards-rules-and-campaign-regulations-approved-93rd-oscarsr):  "For This Awards Year Only, Streamed Films To Be Eligible for Oscars®"

Answer (score -4):

If/when Netflix makes good enough movies the Academy will change the rules.

Netflix looked into releasing some movies in theaters in France to qualify for Cannes (or another of the awards there) but French movie releases were not allowed to be shown on TV/Streamed for 2 years (or another prohibitive time period.)  Netflix looked into releasing their movies just so they can qualify for the awards.  So they will probably do the same in the US if their movies are good enough.  But if releasing them are too restrictive on their streaming business, they wont. And then it will be over to the Academy to change their rules.

There is a risk that some other award ceremony recognises Netflix and Amazon etc that one day may have all the best films, marginalising the Academy Awards.  So they would change their rules if it came to that...

In 2015, four major US cinema chains refused to screen the Idris Elba war drama Beasts of No Nation due to Netflix’s decision to release the film online at the same time as in cinemas, which violated the US’s own rule that says there has to be a 90-day delay between theatrical and home entertainment releases.  So it is unlikely Netflix will pander to the academy's rules.

UPDATE 2020 - they are allowed this year.  And [the New York Post](https://nypost.com/2020/04/30/the-snooty-oscars-should-accept-streaming-movies-permanently/) thinks they should be every year as that is how people like to watch high quality films - linking inclusion in Oscars to quality of film - if Oscars are to be relevant.

> So, pouting, the academy relented and let streaming into the party.
>   Desperate times, desperate measures, right? But allowing the most
>   easily accessible films to participate in award season should not be a
>   compromise, but a long overdue, totally rational shift in policy. The
>   new streaming eligibility rule must not fade away with a vaccine, but
>   be woven into the fabric of future Oscars ceremonies. That is, if the
>   academy craves a sliver of relevance anymore. Oscars 2021 will allow
>   streamed films due to the coronavirus The truth is that today,
>   streaming and on-demand watching are audiences’ preferred ways for
>   experiencing high-quality films. Plain and simple.

Comment: Whether the movies are "good enough" is irrelevant. Many crappy movies qualify for the Oscars. What matters are the rules for consideration.

Comment: Not sure you understood the answer.  There were specif films Netflix were looking to release for Cannes and Cannes wanted them in.  Cannes are looking to change the rules for entry now.  If Netflix did not have those moveies of that quality they would not be looking to change the rules.  My point is that netflix have the oportunity to have thier movies qulaify for the oscars.  There is nothing instrinsic about Netflix that disqualifies.  And in the coming years the rules that disqualify their movies is likely to change if their quality is high enough.

Comment: I was referring to your opening line, which indicates Netflix original movies are not currently considered for Oscar nomination because the Academy doesn't think they are good enough.

Comment: That's not what it says.  It says they do not qualify because of the rules, but the rules are likely to change based on quality.

Comment: The rules don't account for 'quality'. Quality is subjective. That's why they vote on the Oscars in the first place. The rules account for how and when films are distributed. I doubt the rules will ever change to account for whether films are "good enough" or not "good enough". The bottom line is that your first sentence is completely false. Netflix already makes good movies. Bad movies already qualify for and get nominated for some Oscars. Good/bad has nothing to do with it.

Comment: If the oscars can only include crappy, as you say, movies - because the rest are being streamed and not in the cinema - why would they not change their rules?  If they dont another awards ceremony will include them and the oscars will become irrelevant.

Comment: I did not say the Oscars *only* include crappy movies. I said it includes some. But like I also said, quality is subjective. The Academy may well change their rules to allow Netflix movies. They will ***never*** change them to do so because Netflix movies become "good enough"; they will do it because they don't care about restricting the distribution model.

Comment: Also, there are many movie award ceremonies, like the Golden Globes, the SAG awards, the Emmy's, People's Choice, Hollywood Film, Cannes, MTV Movie Awards, etc. The Oscars are not going anywhere any time soon even though many of those other ceremonies have different/less stringent qualifying criteria.

Comment: @Jon - your simplest course of action here is to remove the first sentence from your answer. This is the thing that people are objecting to and downvoting you for, not the details about other festivals.

Comment: @flith thanks but Im not a fan of censorship.

Comment: @Jon, that's why you're getting so much stick. It's not censorship, it's the removal of an *opinion-based observation* as the lead-in to a *fact-based answer*. It has no place here.

Comment: I am entitled to disagree and let the haters hate.

Comment: The theatrical release in Los Angeles County is a pretty low bar. There are a number of theaters which pretty much specialize in being that theater, usually a cineplex - with popular movies in all the big screens and these "Statutory Oscar movies" in the little tiny screens with 30 seats in them. They don't actually expect to sell any tickets and some movies famously make trivial amounts like  $400 in "worldwide" theatrical release.

Comment: @jon I think you misunderstand how freedom of speech works.  The internet has no freedom of speech. What it has is *freedom of the press* which belongs to them that owns one.  In this case Stackexchange. They get to set the rules, and if one values freedom of speech, one must respect those rules.  Misusing their platform, disobeying the rules is censoring *them*.  [ObMovieRef](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHT3bdczPaM)

Comment: @harper see the comment on Beasts of no nation.  The reason not to release the movie is not based on not finding a suitable cinema.  I think this answer fits the rules and the downvoters have a narrow focus and dont understand the answer, and cant see past the 1st line.  You think the answer does not fit the rules.  So use your tools available.  I do not want to change my answer because others want me to.  Wiki definition: Censorship is the suppression of ... public communication ...on the basis that such material is considered objectionable ... as determined by community consensus.

Comment: Then maybe it ought to be the *last* line.

Comment: I also thought, that is was a poor answer, by the first line, but it raised good points about what would force a rule change and why the current ones theoretically and practically exclude Netflix movies. While Jon is being difficult, I can understand his decision to keep his answer the way he wanted it structured. People don't like it and they downvote, which he is fine with. I think it is still a good answer, though.